# Prism named P.ABCD with height 5 cm, inside a cube with side 24 cm named ABCDEFGH. Q in middle EF. Find the distance from Q to PAB.

Tags: geometry

Prism named P.ABCD with height 5 cm, inside a cube with side 24 cm named ABCDEFGH. Q in middle EF. Find the distance from Q to PAB.[image]

I draw it
[image]

SQ = 24 cm, QR = 12 cm, PT = 5 cm

QS^2 - x^2 = QP^2 - (13-x)^2

After i get x i can count QY, but i cant get the answer.

What should i do?

Comment: Your "prism" is a pyramid, I suppose...

Comment: Double area of triangle $QSP$ is $24\cdot12=288$. Take now $SP=13$ as base: the altitude is then $\displaystyle QY={288\over13}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly written down the equation.
$$|QS|^2 - x^2 = |QP|^2 - (13-x)^2 \qquad \text{with}~ |QS| = 24.$$
Now all you need is to plug in
$$|QP|^2  = |QR|^2 + |RP|^2  \qquad \text{with}~ |QR| = 12 ~\text{as you already noted,}$$
and
$$|RP|=|RT|-|PT|=24-5=19$$

So that you can solve for $x$ and then |QY| as planned.
[image]

#### Spoiler alert: $\quad$ solution below

Please move the cursor over the yellow block to reveal it.

> $$\begin{alignat}{2}&&24^2 - x^2 &= (19^2 + 12^2) - (13-x)^2 \\ &\implies & 576 - x^2 &= 361 + 144 - 169 + 26 x - x^2\\ &\implies& x &= \frac{576-361-144 + 169}{26} = \frac{120}{13} \approx 9.23077 \end{alignat} \\ |QY|^2=|QS|^2 - x^2 \\ \implies \text{desired distance} = |QY| = \sqrt{24^2 - \Bigl(\frac{120}{13}  \Bigr)^2} = \frac{288}{13}\approx 22.153846$$Note that we have the similar triangles with the $5$-$12$-$13$ Pythagorean triple: $\triangle SPT \sim \triangle QSY$. Namely, the fact that the numerator of $|QY|$ is a whole number (despite coming out of a square root) is not a coincidence.
> Also, as commented by Aretino, one can obtain this same answer quicker via $$|QY|=\frac{\text{twice the area of}~\triangle QSP}{|SP|}=2\cdot\frac{|QS|\cdot |QR|}{|SP|} = 2\cdot\frac{\frac12\cdot 24 \cdot 12}{13} = \frac{288}{13}$$

Comment: Do you try to finish this?

Comment: I thought you wanted to solve it yourself.

Comment: The reason i didnt finish it, cuz i stuck at $\sqrt{{24}^2 - {\frac{120}{13}}^2} $ i thought i was doing wrong. But how you can solve the sqrt?

Comment: No i edited the comment

Comment: Note that $120 = 24 \cdot 5$, and note that the first term in the square root is $(24)^2 \cdot (13)^2$.

Comment: Like I said in the post, we have the 5-12-13 Pythagorean triple. $\displaystyle\sqrt{{24}^2 - {\frac{(24\cdot 5)^2}{13^2}}} = \frac1{13}\sqrt{(24\cdot 13)^2 - (24\cdot 5)^2}= \frac1{13}\sqrt{(24\cdot 12)^2}$.
Hope that clarifies it now.